# Getting started Java with Linux OS

Tags: java, linux

I know this is very basic question, but these days I have done all my Java programs on Windows OS. But now I like to go with Linux.
How JDK and all be installed in Linux OS?

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Comment: This depends greatly on your linux distribution and version.

Answer (score 5):

That is dependent on the distribution you are using -- provide more details so people can be more helpful.

In most distributions however this is as simple as installing a package from the official repositories.

For example, in Debian/Ubuntu etc. you can do:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

which will get you both the JDK and the JRE which is a dependency.

Comment: @giri this answer is correct, but please specify which distro you're using because that command won't work on all distros.

Comment: or, if you're using a recent ubuntu version, just open up the software center, search for java and install that. It's easier for "newcomers" this way ;)

Comment: The jre is a dependency of the jdk, so the second argument is redundant.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel: thanks, I wasn't sure (I don't use Ubuntu so I couldn't test). Removed it.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk openjdk-6-demo openjdk-6-doc
```

gets you the SDK, its demos and documentation.  You should then be able to run the first set of examples.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your distribution. In Ubuntu you would do something like this (as root)...

```
# aptitude search jdk
```

After your choice, you install it.

```
# aptitude install sun-java6-jdk
```

Don't bother about downloading anything from any website. The package manager (apt-get, aptitude) is doing that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Many Linux distributions package the OpenJDK into their repositories so you can install Java like any other application.  If you want the Sun version of Java then you can download a bin or rpm file directly from Sun/Oracle that you can install manually.

The Sun/Oracle version can be found here: http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/widget/jdk6.jsp  Just select Linux as your platform in the form.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to others' answers:  If you need Java packages beyond what your distro provides, then check out the [JPackage project](http://www.jpackage.org/).  JPackage provides RPMs (so it won't work on Debian or Ubuntu, unless you use [Alien](http://wiki.debian.org/Alien)) of a large number of Java libraries, frameworks, and tools.

Answer (score 0):

As people have noted, you can use apt-get to install the JDK:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

Also, if you're looking for a graphical editor, Eclipse is a good one, especially when you're not very familiar with Unix operating systems.  It also should come with the JDK included with the default install.  You can download that with:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

As Tedil mentioned, you can also get this without the console work via Ubuntu's Software Center in the Applications menu from the top bar.